# Issue in configuring a TAPI address line

Tags: tapi

I am developing a telephony application with TAPI API's. I am able to get some sample codes to develop an Application using TAPI API's, but I am not able to configure Address for the TAPI application to work. Any help would be of greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ganesan S

Adding piece of code , which I have tried

```
    private int InitializePhoneDevices()
    {
        var parms = new PHONEINITIALIZEEXPARAMS();
        parms.dwTotalSize = parms.dwNeededSize = parms.dwUsedSize = Marshal.SizeOf(parms);
        parms.dwOptions = NativeMethods.PHONEINITIALIZEEXOPTION_USEEVENT;
        parms.dwCompletionKey = 0;
        parms.hEvent = IntPtr.Zero;

        int numDevices; uint hTapi;

        int rc = NativeMethods.phoneInitializeEx(out hTapi, 0, null, _appName,
                out numDevices, ref _phoneVersion, ref parms);
        if (rc == NativeMethods.PHONEERR_OK)
        {
            _hTapiPhone = new HTPHONEAPP(hTapi, true);
            _evtReceivedPhoneEvent.SafeWaitHandle = new SafeWaitHandle(parms.hEvent, false);

            _phoneArray = new List<TapiPhone>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++)
            {
                _phoneArray.Add(new TapiPhone(this, i));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            numDevices = 0;
        }
        return numDevices;
    }
```

The number of devices in the list is always coming as empty, that is the problem, what configurations I have top do in my system to get it populated.

Comment: can you please show us what you've tried so far, code etc thanks

Comment: added the piece of code , which I have tried, can u please add your comments

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain your PBX is exposing via Phone Devices? In my experience most TAPI 2.2 drivers will expose via Line Devices. Try using lineInitializeEx instead.

[MSDN lineInitializeEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735983(v=vs.85).aspx)